# Userform textbox temporarily enlarged when clicked on to reflect size of content entered in

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox, userform

How can I enlarge a textbox to fit in all the content when someone is typing in it? Currently it just only lets you see the content that fits in the textbox, however I need to make it reflective of the text being entered for users to be able to check and verify the content being put into it. I would need a solution that only temporarily enlarges it when the textbox is clicked on and then when another question is clicked on it reverts to the normal size it was originally.

I was thinking of something like the code below but that didn't fufill all the necessary conditions:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Click()
 TextBox1.Height = TextBox1.LineCount * 10
End Sub
```

Comment: You can create sub to check lenght of input on textbox change event. if some lenght then textbox.height = xx. textbox multiline required. return to default height on textbox lostfocus event

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an idea of how to do this. It will need to be tailored to fit your specific userform, but the general structure of my idea should be suitable.

I have the default values of the Userform and TextBox saved during the `UserForm_Initialize` event. Then during any `TextBox_Enter` or `TextBox_Change` event, the UserForm does a check to see if it needs to resize the box to fit the new contents. Then during the `TextBox_Exit` event, the UserForm and TextBox return to default size.

This is the code module of my UserForm:

```vb
Private USERFORM_DEFAULT_HEIGHT As Integer
Private USERFORM_DEFAULT_WIDTH As Integer
Private TEXTBOX1_DEFAULT_HEIGHT As Integer
Private TEXTBOX1_DEFAULT_WIDTH As Integer

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    USERFORM_DEFAULT_HEIGHT = Me.Height
    USERFORM_DEFAULT_WIDTH = Me.Width
    TEXTBOX1_DEFAULT_HEIGHT = Me.TextBox1.Height
    TEXTBOX1_DEFAULT_WIDTH = Me.TextBox1.Width
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If Me.ActiveControl Is Me.TextBox1 Then Resize_To_Contents Me.TextBox1
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "ThisWorkbook.UserForm1.Resize_To_Contents(UserForm1.TextBox1)"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Me.TextBox1.Height = TEXTBOX1_DEFAULT_HEIGHT
    Me.TextBox1.Width = TEXTBOX1_DEFAULT_WIDTH
    Me.Height = USERFORM_DEFAULT_HEIGHT
    Me.Width = USERFORM_DEFAULT_WIDTH
End Sub

Public Sub Resize_To_Contents(TB As Object)
    Dim NewHeight As Integer
    Dim NewWidth As Integer

    If Not TB.WordWrap Then
        NewWidth = Len(TB.Text) * 5 + 4 'this fit my screen and default font size, you may need to adjust it.
    Else
        NewWidth = TB.Width
    End If
    
    NewHeight = TB.LineCount * 10.6 'this fit my screen and default font size, you may need to adjust it.
    
    If NewHeight > TB.Height Then
        Me.Height = Me.Height + NewHeight - TB.Height
        TB.Height = NewHeight
    End If
    
    If NewWidth > TB.Width Then
        Me.Width = Me.Width + NewWidth - TB.Width
        TB.Width = NewWidth
    End If
End Sub
```

The reason for doing `Application.OnTime` is because `LineCount` requires the TextBox to have Focus, which doesn't happen until *after* the event finishes. So I tell the script to wait 1 second and then run, so that the TextBox will have focus and I can use `LineCount`.

Comment: I would add to use _Courier_ font type as it's mono-spaced (every character has the same spacing) so it makes it easy to calculate the width. It's not the prettiest font but will do the job better than any other font.

Comment: Is there a way to make the enlarged text boxes impose itself over other textboxes underneath temporarily until the focus is changed? For example textbox2 would be right below textbox1 and currently this method works to enlarge it and when focus is changed it shrinks it back to default sizing, but when typing out a long answer it cuts into textbox2 with textbox2 overlaying over the text entered in textbox1.

Comment: @2acb_John_Suren When the TextBox gains focus, use `Me.TextBox1.ZOrder fmTop`. When it loses focus, pull the next active shape to the top, if needed.